# Classifying predicted values using a prediction interval

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am running a simple linear regression to predict price for a particular data set. I would like to not only compute metrics such as mean squared error but also be able to compute which testing instances are within a prediction interval of 10% of the actual price (i.e actual price is in the range predicted price +/- 10%). But I'm not sure what the best way to do this is or if an existing package can help. I'm currently working with numpy arrays for my X and Y training data.

```
# Load in train test split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = prepare_data()

# fit model 
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute predictions
y_pred = lm.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the values of `y_test`, you can use `np.select`
So in your case the condition is values of `y_test` that are within 10% of `y_pred`

```py
condition = [abs(y_pred - y_test)/y_test < 0.1]
choice = [y_test]
result = np.select(condition, choice)
```

Comment: Upvoted for the excellence and clarity of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the sklearn provides this built in or not but you can do it by yourself as following:

```
abs(y_test - y_pred)/y_test * 100
```

Do this for all `y_pred`'s and it will give you % variation of predicted value from actual value.

For example if actual value is 200 and your prediction is 210, then what above code will do is:

```
>>> abs(200-210)/200 *100
>>> 5 %
```